# How to use Dijkstra's Algorithm for finding shortest path with vertex constraint

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I have been stuck on this problem for two days now and still no progress. Basically the problem is as follows:
Given an undirected simple weighted and connected graph, we have to find the shortest walk from a given source to a given destination while visiting at least one vertex from a given set, A and at least one vertex from the set B with the added constraint that the vertex from set B should always come after visiting the vertex from set A.
Set A and B are disjoint and there can be vertices in the graph which neither belong to A nor B. There is a single source and destination vertex.

I tried decomposing the shortest path into one which visits a vertex, v in A from source, then from v to another w in B and then from w to destination. This can be done using 3 passes of Dijkstra with different starting vertices respectively. But, I would have to choose the minimum such v resulting in O(V*E*log(V)) complexity where V = number of vertices and E = number of edges.
I am terribly stuck on how to do this in O(E*log(V)), since the question asks so, i.e. using only O(1) Dijkstra runs. Can anybody please help me?

Edit: We can't construct a new graph or modify it as some people are suggesting to construct a level graph.
I have to modify the Dijkstra routine somehow to solve this.
[Graph. Blue vertices are the set A, purple ones set B. Home is 0 and Destination is 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTMN3.jpg)
In this graph(see link) for example, the shortest walk should be: 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 with total cost = 6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5483526+graph+layering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (to me) way to solve such problems is to separate graph vertices into "levels" (like stories in a building) and possibly replicate some vertices between more than one level.

In your case, there will be 5 levels, levels 1, 3 and 5 containing all vertices while level 2 only has A vertices and level 4 only has B. The start vertex is at level 1 and the end is at level 5. The original edges are replicated within each level and between adjacent levels.

Any path in the modified graph passes through an A vertex and after that through a B vertex, because any path must pass through all 5 levels in order.

This arrangement does not care if there are additional A and B vertices in any order, in addition to the mandatory pair in the required order (so x-x-x-A-B-A-B-x-x-x is allowed). If you need to exclude those, remove all B vertices from levels 1 and 3, and all A vertices from levels 3 and 5.

Comment: How does this level ordering ensure optimal path between source and destination. For eg, it could be that first I go from source to B and then from B to A then again from A to B. It is not clear on how can we use this level ordering? Can you please comment on how can we modify Dijkstra to solve this constraint problem?

Comment: It is not clear what your concern is. Every path in the original graph that satisfies the A-then-B requirement has a corresponding path in the modified graph. Conversely, every path in the modified graph has a corresponding path in the original graph that satisfies the A-then-B requirement. The shortest path here is therefore the shortest path there.

Comment: I understood your new level ordered graph, but the problem is I can't modify or construct a new graph, you see. I can only write a new routine to solve this problem. So any ideas on how Dijkstra can perhaps be modified to ensure the constraint is followed?

Comment: You don't need to "create a new graph", whatever that means. In Dijkstra you have a queue of vertices. Just add several copies of each vertex to the queue, with an appropriate label.

Comment: @MohammadWasih I have a similar problem, How did you implement this one?

Answer (score 1):

As @n.'pronouns' m. pointed out, we can solve this problem by graph layering.
Specifically for my case, just add a new source vertex and add edges from this source vertex to all the edges of vertices belonging to A of original graph. The weight of these edges would be the same as the shortest path found from original source to this vertex in original graph.
Similarly, you add a new destination vertex and add edges from all B vertices to this new vertex and the weight of the edge is again the shortest path from the B vertex to original destination vertex in original graph.
Now if you run Dijkstra from new source to new destination, you see that atleast one A vertex would be visited before B vertex finally ending at new destination. This path is indeed the shortest path.